# opencpu package or namespace load failed for 'rJava'

Tags: r, opencpu

I have `install.packages("rJava")` in R

it is ok

`library(rJava)` is ok

but when I issue GET request "../library/rJava/R" to opencpu server, it can't be accessed.

`../library/rJava` is ok

error:HTTP 400 Bad Request,package or namespace load failed for 'rJava'

and /var/log/kern.log: `kernel: [92053.630574] type=1400 audit(1427769314.925:227): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="opencpu-main" name="/proc/21078/stat" pid=21078 comm="sh" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=33 ouid=33`

My Configuration:

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)

Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

Java:version "1.7.0_75"

opencpu:1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in opencpu and it is in their github too . It is not yet fixed.  Please refer this link https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu/issues/123 for more details about this bug. I faced this same error when I tried to invoke a function in a package called mallet which depends on rJava.